# How to use string for .get using fstream?

Tags: c++

I need to use string instead of char to write several characters at once.

I want the first cycle to take data from the file and the second cycle to go through the `string` cycle to `\0`
since in the future I want to receive 2 or 4 characters at a time.

Can I implement this to get `.get` working through `string`?

```
fstream fs("file.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | ios::binary);
        for (string i; fs.get(i);) {
            cout << i;    
        }
```

Comment: Did you try to compile the code? Where did you find the `fstream::get()` version for the string? There are the [overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) only for `char*`.

Comment: Do you want to read lines from the file, or words? Or just blocks of a fixed length?

Comment: @FireLancer fixed length block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`istream::get` with a c-string reads up to n characters, or a delimiter, default newline (very similar to `istream::getline`, but it *leaves the delimiter in the stream*, while `getline` consumes it).

To read fixed length blocks regardless there is `istream::read`, and `istream::gcount` says how much was actually read. Unfortunately neither have an overload for `std::string` specifically, the main downside being having to size (and thus initialize) a string first.

Putting them together you can get something like:

```
std::string buffer;
std::fstream is("file.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
while (is)
{
    buffer.resize(128); // Whatever size you want
    is.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size()); // Read into buffer, note *does not null terminate* // C++17
    //is.read(&buffer[0], buffer.size()); // Older C++
    buffer.resize(is.gcount()); // Actual amount read. Might be less than requested, or even zero at the end or a read failure.
    std::cout << "Read " << buffer.size() << " characters." << std::endl;
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

---

For `getline` specifically, there is `std::getline` which handles `std::string` for you:

```
std::string buffer;
std::fstream is("file.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
while (std::getline(is, buffer))
{
    std::cout << "Line: " << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

Note that both `get` and `getline` can use some other delimiter, so it doesn't have to be "lines".